# "AS" pseudo operator syntax in clsql

Tags: mysql, sql, lisp, common-lisp

I cannot figure out what would be the correct syntax for aliasing a field in the SQL query builder in clsql.

Below is an example, as I would imagine it might work (but obviously it doesn't):

```
(defun number-of-goods-you-have-the-most? ()
  (clsql:select [item_id] [as [count [*]] 'num]
        :from [table]
        :where [is [null [sale_date]]]
        :group-by [item_id]
        :order-by '((num :desc))
        :limit 1))
```

I could've make it something like `'|count(*) as num|` but that's surely not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try `(clsql:select [item_id] [count [*]] [as] 'num] ...)`?

Comment: I'm happy you made it work. Usually if you want any SQL operator that isn't easily included into clsql, just place it where it would be in the SQL query, with square brackets.